# I getting error while executing a web application using MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, web-development-server

```html
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb : //localhost:27017/taskmanager',{ useNewUrlParser: true ,useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log('database connected'))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));



module.exports = mongoose;
```

I am getting error as MongoParseError: Invalid connection string[vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bMT6.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/x', {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useFindAndModify: false,
useCreateIndex: true  });
```

Is what I’m using on a personal project, in your case I believe what’s causing the error is the space between mongodb and the rest of the string.

```
'mongodb : //localhost:27017/taskmanager'
```

As posted in the Mongoose Documentation:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options...', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much ,, I have been struggling for hours